# Unable to identify chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, pcb

Unable to identify below chip (should be touch controller)

[image: unable to identify chip]

this is on a wifi 4 channel switch - overall PCB as below
[image: Overall PCB of a wifi switch]

Any help in identifying chip appreciated, need to unload custom firmware to the board which i think is esp8266 based.

Comment: Bruh, you just cross post this to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/677542/help-me-identify-a-chip-marked-145az01-a2e1a53-c

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on  electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: thats fine - thanks.